# Overlay curves on same plot at each compilation

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder

Since a update I have an issue with my ploting in Matplotlib. I use Spyder (as IDE) from Anaconda and do a lot of overlay stuff by running different programm in other to compare simulation.

But recently this does not work anymore ! For example if I run this code (with and without plt.draw does not change anything, and plt.gca as well) :

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = np.linspace(1,50,20)
x = f**1
y = f**1.2

fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(f,x)
ax.plot(f,y)
plt.draw()
```

And re-run it by change a variable as :

```
y = f**1.5
```

The output is not what I used to have and expected
[image: Plot obtained after 2 compilation]

I would expected a update of the axis and a third curves (a green one by default) that appears, but no.

Do you have any idea, I turn crazy to find out with this change et how...
Sorry if it's easy, sometimes the easiest thing to do it's the hardest to see.

Thanks and have nice day

Comment: `The problem is running ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)` twice. You should only run that once, and use the same `ax` the next time.  Or just use `ax = plt.gca()`

Comment: Hi ! Thanks, I just add a check figure condition and gca() and it's working. But I don't know why I never had issues before without putting that... Anyway that's working, thank you :)